# Security Configuration Spring Boot 6.1 error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am watching Amigoscode in Youtube and follow his tutorial about how to setup spring boot security but it is a little outdated and most things are deprecated can someone help me set up SecurityCongifuration this is my code(also i cant find many information in internet how to solve it):

```
 @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return http.build();

    }
```

this is the code he provides in the tutorial.

Comment: which error do you have? can you add stacktrace or something?

Comment: To be honest, the code you provided doesn't seem outdated at all.

Comment: it is in red and says it is deprecated and marker for removal for(.authorizeHttpRequests(),.and(),.sessionManagement())

Comment: amigoscodes spring security implementation is very insecure and very bad and should be taken down. He is implementing JWTs as sessions which is very insecure. He has not read a single line of the spring security documentation and that tutorial is just bringing problems teaching people very bad practices.

Comment: if you want to learn spring security i suggest you read the documentation and start out by implementing formlogin using session cookies. Read https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/architecture.html and https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/architecture.html and then implement https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/passwords/form.html

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is how it should be because of functionals are deprecated

```
 @Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
http
    .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
    .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize.requestMatchers("/api/v1/auth/**","/swagger-ui/**","/v3/api-docs/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
    )
    .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
    .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
    http.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    return http.build();
}
```